# Circular Dependency in my .NET 5.0 C# project - how can I solve it?

Tags: c#, server-side, .net-5, circular-dependency, blazor-webassembly

I have the following project structure with following namespaces:

- Solution: `ProjectName`

  - SubProject: `ProjectName.Shared`

    - Contains Namespace: `ProjectName.Shared.Logging`
  - SubProject: `ProjectName.DbContext`

    - Has project reference: `ProjectName.Shared`
    - Uses Namespace: `ProjectName.Shared.Logging`

The `DbContext` project is currently using a project reference to the `Shared` project because we would like to log data via a solution-wide used Logger.

Now it shall be changed so that the Logger shall also write in some database. It would mean to me that it would become a circular project dependency if I try to add `ProjectName.DbContext` as a project reference in `ProjectName.Shared`.

It would look like this then:

- Solution: `ProjectName`

  - SubProject: `ProjectName.Shared`

    - Contains Namespace: `ProjectName.Shared.Logging`
    - **Has project reference: `ProjectName.DbContext`**
    - **Uses Namespace: `ProjectName.DbContext`**
  - SubProject: `ProjectName.DbContext`

    - **Has project reference: `ProjectName.Shared`**
    - **Uses Namespace: `ProjectName.Shared.Logging`**

I was considering creating a new SubProject called `ProjectName.Logging`, but I could not see how it would solve my circular dependency problem; `ProjectName.Logging` would need `ProjectName.DbContext` and the other way around, too.

Does someone have an idea how to solve that circular dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

four options:

1. combine the `ProjectName.Shared` and `ProjectName.DbContext` assemblies
2. see whether one of them could declare an interface - perhaps `ProjectName.DbContext` could declare and accept an `IDbLogger` interface, which is then *implemented* in `ProjectName.Shared` and passed in, so it can do logging without having to know the details
3. create an *additional* package *underneath* which has the logging abstractions, which both `ProjectName.Shared` and `ProjectName.DbContext` would reference
4. like 3, but using the pre-rolled `ILogger[<T>]` from [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions)

(it is also *technically* possible to create a genuinely circular build, but it is *horribly* complicated, *very* brittle, and you should not consider it as anything other than a hack of absolute last resort)